# Is this true for subspaces in a normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis

That any one dimensional subspace of a normed space satisfies the parallelogram law. How do I prove this, or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Note that all norms on a one-dimensional space are multiples of each other

Comment: Write down the parallelogram law with vectors $\lambda v, \mu v$, and check that everything works.